# Crosstalk + leaflet + plotly - non-persistent selection

Tags: javascript, r, leaflet, plotly, htmlwidgets

I have a reproducible example taken from https://bl.ocks.org/timelyportfolio/5ab450e90ee510f4df9758b9ec5a8ad0.

```
library(sf)
library(plotly)
library(leaflet)
library(crosstalk)
library(htmltools)

boroughs<- st_read("http://services5.arcgis.com/GfwWNkhOj9bNBqoJ/arcgis/rest/services/nybb/FeatureServer/0/query?where=1=1&outFields=*&outSR=4326&f=geojson")
boroughs$x <- seq(1:5)
boroughs$y <- seq(2,10,2)

boroughs_sd <- SharedData$new(
  boroughs,
  key=~BoroCode,
  # provide explicit group so we can easily refer to this later
  group = "boroughs"
)

map <- leaflet(boroughs_sd) %>%
  addProviderTiles(providers$CartoDB.Positron) %>%
  addPolygons(
    data=boroughs,
    layerId = ~BoroCode,
    color = "#444444",
    weight = 1,
    smoothFactor = 0.5,
    opacity = 1.0,
    fillOpacity = 0.5,
    fillColor = ~colorQuantile("Greens", x)(x)#,
    #  turn off highlight since it interferes with selection styling
    #   if careful with styling could have both highlight and select
    #    highlightOptions = highlightOptions(color = "white", weight = 2)
  )

# borrow from https://github.com/r-spatial/mapedit/blob/master/R/query.R#L73-L132
#   to select/deselect features but instead of Shiny.onInputChange
#   use crosstalk to manage state
add_select_script <- function(lf, styleFalse, styleTrue, ns="") {
  ## check for existing onRender jsHook?

  htmlwidgets::onRender(
    lf,
    sprintf(
      "
      function(el,x) {
      var lf = this;
      var style_obj = {
      'false': %s,
      'true': %s
      }

      // instead of shiny input as our state manager
      //   use crosstalk
      if(crosstalk) {
      var ct_sel = new crosstalk.SelectionHandle()
      ct_sel.setGroup('boroughs')
      ct_sel.on('change', function(x){
      if(x.sender !== ct_sel) { //ignore select from this map
      lf.eachLayer(function(lyr){
      if(lyr.options && lyr.options.layerId) {
      var id = String(lyr.options.layerId)
      if(
      !x.value  ||
      (Array.isArray(x.value) && x.value.indexOf(id) === -1)
      ) {
      toggle_state(lyr, false)
      toggle_style(lyr, style_obj.false)
      }
      if(Array.isArray(x.value) && x.value.indexOf(id) > -1) {
      toggle_state(lyr, true)
      toggle_style(lyr, style_obj.true)
      }
      }
      })
      }
      })
      }

      // define our functions for toggling
      function toggle_style(layer, style_obj) {
      layer.setStyle(style_obj);
      };
      function toggle_state(layer, selected, init) {
      if(typeof(selected) !== 'undefined') {
      layer._mapedit_selected = selected;
      } else {
      selected = !layer._mapedit_selected;
      layer._mapedit_selected = selected;
      }
      if(typeof(Shiny) !== 'undefined' && Shiny.onInputChange && !init) {
      Shiny.onInputChange(
      '%s-mapedit_selected',
      {
      'group': layer.options.group,
      'id': layer.options.layerId,
      'selected': selected
      }
      )
      }

      if(ct_sel) {
      var ct_values = ct_sel.value
      var id = String(layer.options.layerId)
      if(selected) {
      if(!ct_values) {
      ct_sel.set([id])
      }
      if(Array.isArray(ct_values) && ct_values.indexOf(id) === -1) {
      ct_sel.set(ct_values.concat(id))
      }
      }

      if(ct_values && !selected) {
      ct_values.length > 1 ?
      ct_sel.set(
      ct_values.filter(function(d) {
      return d !== id
      })
      ) :
      ct_sel.set(null) // select all if nothing selected
      }
      }

      return selected;
      };
      // set up click handler on each layer with a group name
      lf.eachLayer(function(lyr){
      if(lyr.on && lyr.options && lyr.options.layerId) {
      // start with all unselected ?
      toggle_state(lyr, false, init=true);
      toggle_style(lyr, style_obj[lyr._mapedit_selected]);
      lyr.on('mouseover',function(e){
      var selected = toggle_state(e.target);
      toggle_style(e.target, style_obj[String(selected)]);
      });
      }
      });
      }
      ",
      jsonlite::toJSON(styleFalse, auto_unbox=TRUE),
      jsonlite::toJSON(styleTrue, auto_unbox=TRUE),
      ns
    )
  )
  }

browsable(
  tagList(
    tags$div(
      style = "float:left; width: 49%;",
      add_select_script(
        map,
        styleFalse = list(fillOpacity = 0.2, weight = 1, opacity = 0.4, color="black"),
        styleTrue = list(fillOpacity = 0.7, weight = 3, opacity = 0.7, color="blue")
      )
    ),
    tags$div(
      style = "float:left; width: 49%;",
      plot_ly(boroughs_sd, x = ~x, y = ~y) %>%
        add_markers(alpha = 0.5,text = ~paste('Borough: ', BoroName)) %>%
        highlight(on = "plotly_selected")
    )
  )
)
```

I made a minor change to the code from it's original source so that polygons are highlighted on mouseover rather than click.

My experience with JavaScript is pretty minimal. What do I need to change so that selection of polygons is not persistent (i.e. highlight style only changes when on mouseover and does not remain after the mouse has left that particular polygon)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest to change the following part of code

```
lyr.on('mouseover',function(e){
  var selected = toggle_state(e.target);
  toggle_style(e.target, style_obj[String(selected)]);
});
```

with

```
lyr.on('mouseover',function(e) {
  var selected = toggle_state(e.target, true);
  toggle_style(e.target, style_obj[String(selected)]);
  });
lyr.on('mouseout',function(e) {
  var selected = toggle_state(e.target, false);
  toggle_style(e.target, style_obj[String(selected)]);
});
```

It works on my R.